# Cantor Pairing Function - How was this derived?

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

I'm reviewing my analysis with Marsden and Hoffman's *Elementary Classical Analysis*.

An exercise tasks me with proving that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is denumerable. This is the same as showing $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable.

I must show a bijective function $f:\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ exists.

I drew some integer lattices and trasversed them in many different ways, attempting to find a general formula that would accomplish the goal. I could not manage to do it. I am aware that the Cantor Pairing Function is given by

$$a_{i,j}\mapsto j+\frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}.$$

Could someone give some insight into its derivation? I've seen the exercise before in my past classes, but we were always given the pairing function beforehand. I mapped out the integer lattice for this function, and I can see why it works, but how exactly did Cantor come up with the general function? Did he use the same method I attempted? That is, did he draw lattices, traverse them in different ways, and try to establish the map? Or are there better more analytic ways to do this?

I searched for translations of his papers and found the originals on the University of Göttingen's website, but (obviously) they are all in German.

Comment: I wonder if it helps to note that the fraction there is $1+2+\cdots + (i +j)$?

Comment: Triangular number

Comment: Considering the problem in the framework of the triangular numbers helped immensely. I appreciate both comments very much.